# extracting columns contents only so that all columns for each row are in the same row using Python's BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following python snippet in Jupyter Notebooks that works.
The challenge I have is to extract just the rows of columnar data only

Here's the snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import pandas as pd
page = requests.get("http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston")
page
soup = bs(page.content)
soup
allrows = soup.find_all("p")
print(allrows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear of what you are after but I think it's each individual row of data from URL provided.
I couldn't find a way to use beautiful soup to parse the data you are after but did find a way to separate the rows using .split()

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
    import pandas as pd
    import requests

    page = requests.get("http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston")
    soup = bs(page.content)
    allrows = soup.find_all("p")

    text = soup.text # turn soup into text
    text_split = text.split('\n\n') # split the page into 3 sections
    data = text_split[2] # rows of data

    # create df column titles using variable titles on page
    col_titles = text_split[1].split('\n')
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(14))
    df.columns = col_titles[1:]

    # 'try/except' to catch end of index, 
    # loop throw text data building complete rows
    try:
        complete_row = []
        n1 = 0 #used to track index
        n2 = 1
        rows = data.split('\n') 
        for el in range(len(rows)):
            full_row = rows[n1] + rows[n2]
            complete_row.append(full_row)
            n1 = n1 + 2
            n2 = n2 + 2
    except IndexError:
        print('end of loop')

    # loop through rows of data, clean whitespace and append to df  
    for row in complete_row:   
        elem = row.split(' ')
        df.loc[len(df)] = [el for el in elem if el]

    #fininshed dataframe    
    df
```

Comment: Looking for 506 rows and 14 columns of tabular data

Comment: EDITED: Found the 506 rows x 14 columns you are looking for. My first answer had split the rows into 2 instead of being a full row. This full code produces a dataframe to the description you provided. Hope this helps, any questions please ask

Comment: Just a note that python indenting when entering from Jupyter Notebook here is very fussy. I had to make a few changes to the indents to get it to work. But this is outstanding and you get 5 stars. Very nice.

Comment: If the code helped please accept my answer